# Mysqli not returning a value when i use functions

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I have used a lot of function in my website projects. I had used `mysql`. now I want to convert it into `mysqli` but the problem I am facing is with `mysql_result` my fuction should return 1 valve only

```
// $mysqli is my database connection


function test($id){

$query = "SELECT name FROM members where id= '$id'"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,  MYSQLI_ASSOC);


return $row;
}

$name = test(4);

echo $name;
```

when I do not use functions, just `echo $row` it gives correct result when I put `$id =4;`

Comment: Try `return $row['name'];`

Comment: thanx  bheem Raj sab u and peter solve my problem

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if your question was addressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function definition of `test()` is complete above then you do not have the value of $mysqli. You get that value when you connect to the database and you either need to make it global or pass it in:

```
function test ($id) {
    global $mysqli;
```

or

```
function test ($mysqli, $id) {
```

Comment: Thankx Sir Peter u solved my problem but i cant vote due to reputation less

Comment: sorry 1 more problem #peter that i use 100 functions 3 or 4 time each there in project so i have to pass $mysqli every time 
is there any other way efficient and easy fast

Comment: I'm not aware of another way to handle this more efficiently or easily. You have to somehow get access to the variable within the function and the 2 ways to do that are by passing in a parameter or by using a global...

Comment: oh did now 
ok peter sir i thankx i will use any of 2 ways thanks